# Uncaught Error - Enviando email usando nodemailer e Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, nodemailer

tenho quebrado cabeça há algum tempo tentando criar uma pagina de contatos onde o usuário através da pagina consegue enviar um email. Sou nova com node e por isso tenho passado por alguns problemas. No momento não consigo que minha aplicação reconheça o nodemailer e estou tendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "nodemailer" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Segue meu código para analise. Por favor me ajudem, já passei por vários tutoriais e fóruns mas não consigo resolver o problema.

```js
//CONTROLLER

(function() {
 'use strict'; 
 var ContatoController = ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){  
  
  $scope.formulario = {};
  $scope.formulario.nome;
  $scope.formulario.email;
  $scope.formulario.assunto;
  $scope.formulario.mensagem;  
  
  $scope.enviaEmail = function() {   
   $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/contact-form',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      data: {
       contactNome: $scope.formulario.nome,
             contactEmail: $scope.formulario.email,
             contactAssunto: $scope.formulario.assunto,
             contactMensagem: $scope.formulario.mensagem
      }
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           console.log("Mensagem enviada com sucesso!");
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           console.log("Não deu certo.");
          });         
  };  
}]; 

angular.module('contactForm').controller('ContatoController', ContatoController);  
})();
```

```js
//CONTROLLER-SERVER

'use strict';

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

app.post('/enviaEmail', function(req, res) {
 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'mail.meudominio.com',
  port: '465',
  secure: true,
  auth: {
   user: 'contato@meudominio.com',
   pass: '****'
  } 
 }); 
 
 exports.enviaEmail = function(req, res) {
  var data = req.body;
  
     transporter.enviaEmail({
         from: data.contactEmail,
         to: 'contato@meudominio.com',
         subject: data.contactAssunto + ' - Enviado por: ' + data.contactNome,
         text: data.contactMensagem
     });
  
     res.json(data);
 };
});
```

```js
//ROUTES

'use strict';

 angular.module('contactForm')
  .exports = function(app) {
  
   var core = require('js/server/core.server.controller.js');   
      app.route('/contact-form').post(core.enviaEmail);
  };
```

Comment: Qual a sua versão do `Node.js`? Você pode verificar a versão usando o comando `node -v` no seu `prompt`

Comment: A versão é v8.12.0.

Comment: Já tentou reinstalar seu `Node.js`?

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que você está fazendo uma confusão entre as responsabilidades do `Angular` e do `Node.js`. O `NodeMailer` é um pacote que deve ser executado do lado do servidor, ou seja, pelo `Node.js`. O `Angular` deve requisitar ao `Node.js` que envie o e-mail, fazendo uso de uma rota preestabelecida.

O seu arquivo de rotas no `Node.js` ficará similar ao seguinte:

```
const controller = require('../controller/email.controller');
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/enviarEmail', controller.enviarEmail);

module.exports = router;
```

E o seu `controller` que está referenciado na rota será similar a:

```
const { createTransport } = require('nodemailer');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const configurar = () => {
  const { sendMail } = createTransport({
    host: 'mail.meudominio.com',
    port: '465',
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: 'contato@meudominio.com',
      pass: '****',
    }
  });

  return promisify(sendMail);
};

const enviarEmail = async (req, res) => {
  const { body: { contactEmail, contactAssunto, contactNome, contactMensagem } } = req;
  const enviar = configurar();

  const info = await enviar({
    from: contactEmail,
    to: 'contato@meudominio.com',
    subject: `${contactAssunto} - Enviado por: ${contactNome}`,
    text: contactMensagem,
  });

  res.json({ info, mensagem: 'E-mail enviado com sucesso.' });
};

module.exports = {
  enviarEmail,
}
```

Note que como seu código não é executável fiz apenas uma sugestão de implementação que não tem garantias de funcionamento, afinal não pude testá-lá. Mas note as alterações que deixam claro quais as responsabilidades esperadas do servidor.